# The ErrorProvider's Glyph is sometimes buggy. Why?

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, c++-cli

In my WinForms' application, I use an [ErrorProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.ErrorProvider%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to display errors on some controls (like TextBox or CheckBox).

But the glyph (icon if you prefer) is sometimes buggy: it have some kind of aliasing. These visual glitch is random.

Example of **good** display:

[image: Good display]

Example of **bad** display:

[image: Bad display]

In second picture, you notice **the aliasing in the bounds**! This is very ugly and I found nothing about this glitch on the web.

Have you any idea what can I do to fix it? What is the cause?

Oh, I'm working on Windows XP SP3.

Comment: The problem is that it has no anti-aliasing so it looks blocky.  Very hard to explain, this is just a direct call to a winapi function, DrawIconEx().  You'd only expect it to not anti-alias the icon when it shrinks it to fit the control when the video adapter is operating in a low color mode.  Like the one you get when you use Remote Desktop for example.   You'll need to look such an environmental cause, it isn't .NET that affects this at all.

Comment: That's what I thought too, but it is strange, because I'm in high color mode on a local PC and the GPU's drivers are up to date!

Comment: OK, I've tried on another Windows XP computer and the result is the same.